# which tool supports Flutter error bug reporting tool while running automation scripts

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mobile, automation, functional-testing

I am working in Flutter Android mobile application automation. I am looking for a tool that supports to generate the Bug report while running the automation scripts. Please advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Automation for Mobile Apps** there are many tools *but*

My Answer is - ***Appium*** from my point of view.

Appium is an open source test automation framework for use with native, hybrid and mobile web apps. It drives iOS, Android, and Windows apps using the WebDriver protocol.  Appium can be integrated with Flutter Driver to automate your tests and generate detailed bug reports. You can read the documentation from [*here*](https://appium.io/)